# Why can't I set zoom level on Google Maps with this code?

Tags: google-maps

I have a pretty boilerplate Google Maps code here and when the page loads, it shows the maps and the markers yet the Zoom level is not 14. In fact, I can set Zoom in my script to any value and it doesn't matter. No matter what, the map stays at the same default zoom.

```
function initMap() {
  var bangalore = { lat: 25.94255500, lng: -81.72122700 };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: bangalore
  });

  var locations = [
    @foreach ($results as $result)
    ['{!! $result->CleanStreet !!}', {!! $result->GoogleLat !!}, {!! $result->GoogleLong !!} ],
    @endforeach
  ];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `map.fitBounds(bound)`, that zooms the map to fit the included markers, and won't be effected by changing the initial zoom value for the map (in fact, you can remove the center/zoom values from the map constructor, and as long as you have *some* markers, it will be initialized to show those markers).

Either remove that call and set the initial center and zoom in the `map` constructor, or wait for the `zoom_changed` event to fire after the call to `map.fitBounds(bounds);` and set it then.

related question: [Google maps fitBounds zoom not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242760/google-maps-fitbounds-zoom-not-changing)